# Setting trigonometric function equal to 0

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out how to solve $$\cos(7x)=0$$
I don't know how to solve for the x variable.

Comment: Denote $y = 7x$. Can you solve $\cos(y) = 0$? Once you found all solutions $y_n$, solve for $x$ in $7 x = y_n$.

Answer (score 3):

As we know, if $\displaystyle\cos A=\cos B, A=2m\pi\pm B$ where $m$ is any integer

As $\displaystyle \cos7x=0=\cos\frac\pi2\implies 7x=2m\pi\pm\frac\pi2\ \ \ \ (1)$

This is the general pattern

or

This special method is applicable for $\cos y=\pm1,0$

$\displaystyle\cos7x=0\implies 7x=(2n+1)\frac\pi2\ \ \ \ (2)$  where $n$ is any integer

Can you derive the solution for $\cos y=1,-1$ respectively?

I leave this as exercise for you to prove that the two expressions$(1 ,2)$ are equivalent

Comment: You beat me! $\mathrm{}\\$

Comment: @AhaanRungta, have you  noticed the edited version?

Comment: What edited version?

Comment: @AhaanRungta, may be the current shape :)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're saying?

Comment: @AhaanRungta, I meant the alternative method

Answer (score 3):

We have that any angle $\theta$ that is an odd multiple of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ has a cosine of $0$. So, $7x$ is of the form $(2k+1) \cdot \frac{\pi}{2}$. We have: $$ 7x = \left( 2k + 1 \right) \cdot \frac {\pi}{2} \implies x = \boxed {\dfrac{(2n+1) \cdot \pi}{14}}, $$ for integral $n$.